# The integral inequality

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $f$ be an entire function of exponential type.
 Does the  inequality $|f(a)| \le C \int_{a-1/2}^{a+1/2}|f(x)|\,dx$ hold for every $a \in R$ with an absolute constant 
 $C$? At most, the constant may depend on $f$. The question arises in connection to spectral theory.

Comment: Obviously not for the first question ($f(x)=(1-x^2)^N$ with huge $N$). Still no for the second. What are you really after?

Comment: Adjustment. The function f is assumed not to be a polynomial.

Comment: @Mark: Why exclude polyonimals?  The inequality seems to hold easily
in that case (with $C$ depending on $f$).  @Fedja: What's a counterexample?
It's not obvious that there's an exponential function $f$ that does not
satisfy $|f(a)| \leq C \int_{a-\frac12}^{a+\frac12} \left|f(x)\right| dx$
for any $C$.


Comment: OK, I see what Fedja (might have) had in mind.  Let $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$ 
be a rapidly growing sequence (say $x_n = 10^n$), and define $f$ by
a product with $n$-th order zeros at $x_n \pm 1$ and no other complex zeros.
Then taking $x=x_n$ should show that $C \gg \sqrt n$, because on
$|x - x_n| < 1$ the function will be nearly proportional to
$(1-(x-x_n)^2)^n$.


Comment: Mark (who seems to have lost some login information) asks: Why does such product converge?

Answer (score 1):

No, such an inequality need not hold: one can construct $f$ of
exponential type and a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers such that
$$
\frac1{f(a_n)} \int_{a_n - \frac12}^{a_n - \frac12}
  \left|\phantom.f(x)\right|\phantom. dx
\rightarrow 0.
$$
Indeed if $\{a_n\}$ increases rapidly enough then the growth of $f$
can be arbitrarily slow given that $f$ cannot be a polynomial;
for example, taking $a_n = 10^n$ in the construction below makes
$$
f(z) \ll \exp\left(B \phantom. \log^2 (1+\left|z\right|)\right)
$$
for some absolute constant $B$ (and all $z \in {\bf C}$).

(The following construction spells out what's in Fedja's and my comments,
but neither of us got around to writing it up two months ago, and now
mathoverflow brought it back to the front of the queue, presumably
for lack of an upvoted or accepted answer.)

The idea is to make $f(a_n)$ *smaller* than usual given the growth of $f$,
but still larger than its average on $\left|x-a_n\right| \leq \frac12$,
due to $n$-th order zeros at the edge of that interval.  If $a_n \rightarrow\infty$
fast enough then $f$ can still have exponential or even much slower growth.

Let $\lbrace a_n \rbrace$, then, be a rapidly growing sequence, 
say $a_n = 10^n$; and define $f$ as the real Weierstrass product
$f = \prod_{m=1}^\infty f_m^m
   = f_1 \phantom. f_2^2 \phantom. f_3^3 \phantom. f_4^4 \cdots
$
where
$$
f_m(x) = 
 \Bigl( 1 - \frac{x}{a_m - \frac12} \Bigr)
\phantom.
 \Bigl( 1 - \frac{x}{a_m + \frac12} \Bigr)
$$
is the quadratic polynomial with roots at $a_m \pm 1/2$ such that
$f_m(0) = 1$.
Even with the growing multiplicities of the roots of $f$,
the zeros are sparse enough to assure convergence and slow growth of
the product.

Now for large $n$, if we restrict $x$ to $\left|x-a_n\right| \leq \frac12$
then all the factors $f_m^m$ for $m\neq n$ are essentially constant
on that interval, so $f(x)$ is very nearly
$\phantom.f(a_n)\phantom. \left(\phantom.f_n(x)\left/f_n(a_n)\right.\right)^n$.
Thus
$$
\frac1{f(a_n)} \int_{a_n - \frac12}^{a_n - \frac12}
  \left|\phantom.f(x)\right|\phantom. dx
\sim
\int_{a_n - \frac12}^{a_n - \frac12}
  \left(\frac{f_n(x)}{f_n(a_n)}\right)^n \phantom. dx
= \int_0^1 \bigl(4u(1-u)\bigr)^n \phantom. du,
$$
where $u = x - (a_n - \frac12)$.  The integral is
$(2^n n!)^2 \left/ (2n+1)! \right. = O(n^{-1/2}) \rightarrow 0$, **QED**.

Comment: It is my question. I lost my account. Because of that reason I had to create a new one. Your attention to my question is very kind of you. I approve your answer and vote up. 

Answer (score 0):

Asking for an inequality for entire functions which are NOT polynomials makes no sense.
Take Fedja's polynomial counterexample (or any other polynomial counterexample) and multiply it by $\exp(ix)$. For a counterexample to the second question, take an appropriate product.

Comment: In a deleted answer, Mark asks: Can you kindly explain what is an appropriate product?